# Is there a package in flutter to remove background noise from video?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-plugin, flutter-packages

We want to create a video editing application and need this functionality. Any idea how can we build one?

Answer (score 0):

you need to have in mind how this thing works. then you may take a good decision here.

so about Noise cancellation process can be achieved in one of two ways... one is a recording environment for a few sec then doing some process on the app to make it cleaner like Skype is doing on audio and video calls, and Xaumi is doing on audio capture.

another one is Interesting ... as you know we do live in the AI realm now.. so with AI enhancement. basically, you train a model with example data of before and after the cancellation of noise. Then you can add that trained model to your app. then it can clean any audio.

In this one training and sample audio is key. So to get result you need to train a batter model.